# Can I create an npm package that sets up another npm package?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to create an npm package that would be installed globally, with a binary to call. Calling that binary would set up the initial files for a new project, like your standard folders, standard license and layouts, a package.json with your common dependencies. Then you could call `npm install` to actually set up that project.

Like the [Express application generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html), or like `rails new` does in Ruby. The usage would be like

```
mkdir new_project
cd new_project
myCoolGenerator new
npm install
```

But I'm confused about how I'd implement this. The simple approach, which I'm doing now, is to create the standard vanilla folder, ship it with the generator package, and then just have the main binary use `ncp` to copy that folder into wherever the caller currently is.

My problem there is that I don't know how I can access the folder included in the globally-installed package to copy over. And additionally, npm lets you specify a `files` array in your package.json to specify files included with the package, but it's apparently hardwired to ignore `package.json` from that.

What's the recommended procedure for this sort of thing?

Comment: Maybe this could give you some ideas/recommendations/guidelines: http://yeoman.io/authoring/